# How to inject custom object into scala repl when initializing scala repl

Tags: scala, scala-repl

I'd like to custom the scala repl by injecting some custom value when starting scala repl. What kind of api that I can use for that ? Any difference between scala 2.10 and 2.11 ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scala -i` or `scala -I` to load the **init** file:

```
scala -help
 -i <file>    preload <file> before starting the repl
 -I <file>    preload <file>, enforcing line-by-line interpretation
 ...
```

so you can create your custom file when start, like creating `init.scala` with:

```
val x = "Hello"
val y = "World"
```

and start `scala -i init.scala`

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_71).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> y
res0: String = Hello

scala> x
res1: String = World
```

and about the difference of `scala 2.10` and `scala 2.11`, there should be no difference for this.

Comment: Thanks @chengpohi , Is there scala api that I can use ? I want to create some object at runtime and inject this object into my scala repl.

Comment: Hi @zjffdu, the above way create a init file, and when start **scala repl** it will automatically load the **init files** variables. if you want load this file in **repl runtime**, you can use `:load init.scala` after you start your repl.

Comment: If you don't want to create an intermediate file, you can do something like this  too ` (echo 'val foo="bar"'; cat - ) | scala`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was simply to define an alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias sc="scala -i ~/.scalarc"
```

I often use UUID objects from `java.util` package so it makes sense for me to predefine such import:

*~/.scalarc*:

```
import java.util.UUID
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
import scala.util.{Either, Left, Right}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sbt` then there is a parameter that achieves that:

```
console / initialCommands := "import scala.util.*"
```